# How to push node-red flows to IBM Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red

I am trying to automate the push of a node-red app to Bluemix.
I put my flows into a flow.json file under the defaults directory.
After I push to Bluemix and restage the app, I see the flows in the cloudant nodered database but I do not see them in the node-red editor.
Is there anything else that I need to do?

Comment: If the flow has made it from the file to the Cloudant DB then it should be there. Is there anything in the logs? Also you did refresh the Editor (web ui)?

Comment: @hardillb  I did refresh the Editor 'web ui).  I do see 1 error in the logs when starting up node red:

Comment: @hardillb   APP/0Potentially unhandled rejection [1] TypeError: config.forEach is not a function  
APP/0 at process._tickCallback (node.js:418:13)